# Detect failed edit of channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am making a discord bot which lets users edit a voicechannel name. My code is something like this:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(id)
try:
    await channel.edit(name="new name")
except:
    raise
```

And it raises fine if the name is invalid but not if the name is valid and the change was not successful due to Discords rate limit of I guess 2 edits every 10 minutes.

I think the problem is that there is no error on my end, Discord is just waiting with the response. Is there a way to give my request a timeout of about 5 seconds and raise if it takes too long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check for both an error and a `None` response. Better yet, why not just check that the name after the change is what it should be?

I don't think you can add in a timeout directly into the function call but this is the type of thing you might want to loop and add a `asyncio.sleep` into. Ignoring the first part, you might have something like this:

```
NEW_NAME = "new name"
while True:
    e = None
    try:
        await channel.edit(name=NEW_NAME)
    except Exception as e: pass
    # "channel.name" is pseudo-code. 
    # Use whatever method to check the name.
    if <channel.name> != NEW_NAME: 
        print ("Exception: %s ...(whatever else you want to print)" % e)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # or whatever you think reasonable
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Checking if the name updated works fine and is a brilliant idea which answers my question, why I gave you the checkmark. But after an edit request which fails due to rate limit you can't actually do other things like delete the channel or edit its size, so I'll probably check if edits in the last 10 minutes happened on my end. As mentioned this is a different problem which has nothing to do with this question here. So your answer works, thank you!